Discrepancy in behavior between different implementations of adder module in Verilog multiplier and divider
I'm encountering a puzzling issue with my Verilog code involving a multiplier and divider. I've implemented both modules using a parallel adder component, but I'm getting different results depending on which implementation of the adder I use.
Here's a brief overview of the problem:
I have two implementations of the adder module: one named parallel_adder and another named FA.
When I use the parallel_adder implementation in my multiplier and divider, I get correct results.
However, when I switch to using the CSelA32 implementation of the adder in the same multiplier and divider modules, I start getting incorrect results.
Specifically, when I use 33-bit numbers(the 33th bit is for sign for operation in multiplier and divider), (e.g., 32'd4 and 32'd2), the CSelA32 implementation generates incorrect results, while the parallel_adder implementation produces the correct output.
I've ensured that the widths of inputs and outputs match between the modules, and I've checked the data path and control signals. I've also verified that the module instantiations are correct.
I'm seeking guidance on why the behavior differs between the two implementations and how I can ensure consistent results regardless of which adder implementation I use.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
module parallel_adder #(parameter WIDTH=32)(
    input  wire [WIDTH:0] a, 
    input  wire [WIDTH:0] b,
    input                 cin,
    input                 load,
    output reg  [WIDTH:0] sum,
    output reg            cout
);
    always @* begin
        if(load) {cout, sum} = a+b+cin;
    end
endmodule

HERE I USE CARRY-SELECT ADDER
module FA (
    output reg sum,
    output reg cout,
    input a,
    input b,
    input cin,
    input load
);
  
  always @* begin
    if (load) begin
      sum = a ^ b ^ cin;
      cout = (a & b) | (b & cin) | (cin & a);
    end
  end

endmodule

module MUX2to1_w1 (         //Mux 2to1 for 1 bit
    output reg y,
    input i0,
    i1,
    s
);
  always @(i0, i1, s) begin
    if (s == 1'b0) 
        y = i0;
    else 
        y = i1;
  end
endmodule

module MUX2to1_w4 (         //Mux 2to1 for 4 bits
    output reg [3:0] y,
    input [3:0] i0,
    i1,
    input s
);

  always @(i0, i1, s) begin
    if (s == 1'b0) begin
      y = i0;  
    end else begin
      y = i1;  
    end
  end
endmodule

module RCA4 #(parameter WIDTH=3)(               // Ripple Carry Adder with 4 bits
    input [WIDTH:0] a,
    b,
    input cin,
    input load,
    output [WIDTH:0] sum,
    output cout
);
  wire [WIDTH-1:0] c;

  FA fa0 ( .a(a[0]), .b(b[0]), .cin(cin), .sum(sum[0]), .cout(c[0]), .load(load) );
  FA fa1 ( .a(a[1]), .b(b[1]), .cin(c[0]), .sum(sum[1]), .cout(c[1]), .load(load) );
  FA fa2 ( .a(a[2]), .b(b[2]), .cin(c[1]), .sum(sum[2]), .cout(c[2]), .load(load) );
  FA fa3 ( .a(a[3]), .b(b[3]), .cin(c[2]), .sum(sum[3]), .cout(cout), .load(load) );

endmodule

module CSelA32 #(parameter WIDTH=32) (
    input [WIDTH:0] a,
    input [WIDTH:0] b,
    input cin,
    input load,
    output [WIDTH:0] sum,
    output cout
);

  wire [WIDTH:0] sum0, sum1;
  wire [7:0] c;
  wire [7:0] cout0, cout1;

  RCA4 rca0_0 ( .sum(sum[3:0]), .cout(cout0[0]), .a(a[3:0]), .b(b[3:0]), .cin(1'b0), .load(load) );

  RCA4 rca_other_0[6:1](.sum(sum0[27:4]), .cout(cout0[6:1]), .a(a[27:4]), .b(b[27:4]), .cin(1'b0), .load(load) );
  RCA4 rca_other_1[6:1](.sum(sum1[27:4]), .cout(cout1[6:1]), .a(a[27:4]), .b(b[27:4]), .cin(1'b1), .load(load) );
  MUX2to1_w4 mux_other_sum[6:1](.y(sum[27:4]), .i0(sum0[27:4]), .i1(sum1[27:4]), .s(c[5:0]));
  MUX2to1_w1 mux_other_cout[6:1](.y(c[6:1]), .i0(cout0[6:1]), .i1(cout1[6:1]), .s(c[5:0]));

  RCA4 rca7_0 (.sum(sum0[31:28]), .cout(cout0[7]), .a(a[31:28]), .b(b[31:28]), .cin(1'b0), .load(load)  );
  RCA4 rca7_1 ( .sum(sum1[31:28]), .cout(cout1[7]), .a(a[31:28]), .b(b[31:28]), .cin(1'b1), .load(load)  );
  MUX2to1_w4 mux6543210_sum ( .y (sum[31:28]), .i0(sum0[31:28]), .i1(sum1[31:28]), .s (c[6]) );
  MUX2to1_w1 mux6543210_cout ( .y (c[7]), .i0(cout0[7]), .i1(cout1[7]), .s (c[6]) );

  FA sign (.a(a[32]), .b(b[32]), .cin(c[7]), .sum(sum[32]), .cout(cout), .load(load));


endmodule


I should use a dedicated adder for this project, for instance carry-select adder

Is there a reason you are using popcorn part adders? Verilog supports behavioral adding c = a + b where a,b,c are integral types/vectors. If you make variable c one bit bigger than variables a & b, then there is no carry. It would simplify the use of adders significantly compared to what you are doing. Perhaps this is school work and you have been tasked specifically to create these adders?

The problem here were 2:

You forgot to connect the input signal cin of module CSelA32 to the cin port of the rca0_0 istance of the RCA.
You do not propagate carry out between the first RCA rca0_0 to the first 2 muxes mux_other_sum[0] and mux_other_sum[0].

Here a working solution where cout0[0] is assigned to c[0], propagating the first carry to the 2 muxes.
module CSelA32 #(parameter WIDTH=32) (
    input [WIDTH:0] a,
    input [WIDTH:0] b,
    input cin,
    input load,
    output [WIDTH:0] sum,
    output cout
);

  wire [WIDTH:0] sum0, sum1;
  wire [7:0] c;
  wire [7:0] cout0, cout1;

  RCA4 rca0_0 ( .sum(sum[3:0]), .cout(cout0[0]), .a(a[3:0]), .b(b[3:0]), .cin(cin), .load(load) );
  assign c[0] = cout0[0];
    
    
  RCA4 rca_other_0[6:1](.sum(sum0[27:4]), .cout(cout0[6:1]), .a(a[27:4]), .b(b[27:4]), .cin(1'b0), .load(load) );
  RCA4 rca_other_1[6:1](.sum(sum1[27:4]), .cout(cout1[6:1]), .a(a[27:4]), .b(b[27:4]), .cin(1'b1), .load(load) );
  MUX2to1_w4 mux_other_sum[6:1](.y(sum[27:4]), .i0(sum0[27:4]), .i1(sum1[27:4]), .s(c[5:0]));
  MUX2to1_w1 mux_other_cout[6:1](.y(c[6:1]), .i0(cout0[6:1]), .i1(cout1[6:1]), .s(c[5:0]));

  RCA4 rca7_0 (.sum(sum0[31:28]), .cout(cout0[7]), .a(a[31:28]), .b(b[31:28]), .cin(1'b0), .load(load)  );
  RCA4 rca7_1 ( .sum(sum1[31:28]), .cout(cout1[7]), .a(a[31:28]), .b(b[31:28]), .cin(1'b1), .load(load)  );
  MUX2to1_w4 mux6543210_sum ( .y (sum[31:28]), .i0(sum0[31:28]), .i1(sum1[31:28]), .s (c[6]) );
  MUX2to1_w1 mux6543210_cout ( .y (c[7]), .i0(cout0[7]), .i1(cout1[7]), .s (c[6]) );

  FA sign (.a(a[32]), .b(b[32]), .cin(c[7]), .sum(sum[32]), .cout(cout), .load(load));


endmodule

I hope it will help you.
